# SSL Expiration Date

Tags: ansible

I play this playbook to get amount of days between two expiration certificates dates:

```
---
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no
  connection: local

  tasks:

  - name: Save the old date
    shell:
       cmd: >-
           date --date="$(openssl x509 -noout -dates -in cert1.crt
           | grep 'notAfter' | cut -d= -f2)" --utc +"%d-%m-%Y"
    ignore_errors: true
    args:
       executable: /bin/bash
    register: x1

  - name: Save the new date
    shell:
       cmd: >-
           date --date="$(openssl x509 -noout -dates -in cert2.crt
           | grep 'notAfter' | cut -d= -f2)" --utc +"%d-%m-%Y"
    ignore_errors: true
    args:
       executable: /bin/bash
    register: x2

  - name: Show mount of days with dedug module
    debug:
      var: "{{ (( x2.stdout | to_datetime('%d-%m-%Y')) - ( x1.stdout  | to_datetime('%d-%m-%Y'))).days }}"

  - set_fact:
       diff: "{{ (( x2.stdout | to_datetime('%d-%m-%Y')) - ( x1.stdout | to_datetime('%d-%m-%Y'))).days }}"

  - name: Show diff variable
    debug:
      var: diff
```

The playbook run well and i can show the resultat with debug module (task name: Show mount of days with debug module):

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "357"
}
```

Otherwise the task (Show diff variable) show me a null output:

```
ok: [localhost] => {}
```

I can't find what is wrong with set_fact , anyone have an idea please ?

Comment: Don't call openssl directly - use [openssl_certificate_info_module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/openssl_certificate_info_module.html#ansible-collections-community-crypto-x509-certificate-info-module)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I have a look at your posted output and compare it to mine, there is something wrong:

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "msg": "357"
}
```

That output comes from the debug message. But only with `debug msg={{ value }}` and not with `debug var={{ value }}`. When I do it with var= then I get (in my case) `"32": "32"` as a response.

But that's not the problem. The problem is:

```
- name: Show diff variable
  debug:
    var: diff
```

The name `diff` for the variable is somehow reserved. You need to set the diff as Jinja

```
- name: Show diff variable
  debug:
    var: "{{ diff }}"
```

And then I see

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "32": "32"
}
```

When I rename the variable to `diffa` everything is normal. I can't find any documentation for it.

```
- name: Show mount of days with dedug module
  set_fact:
    diffa: "{{ (( x2 | to_datetime('%d-%m-%Y')) - ( x1  | to_datetime('%d-%m-%Y'))).days }}"

- name: Show mount of days with dedug module
  debug:
    var: diffa
```

output:

```
TASK [Show mount of days with dedug module] *********************************************
ok: [localhost] => {
    "diffa": "32"
}
```